# Composer package requires the wrong version of a dependency package

Tags: github, composer-php, packagist

I have just uploaded my composer package to github and created a package page on packagist.org. My package requires another package to work properly and it is written in the package's composer.json to use "vendor/package": "^0.0.1". However, the page on packagist shows that my package requires "vendor/package": "dev-master", which prevents people to install my package if they didn't explicitly tell composer that minimum-stability should be "dev". The github update works well in packagist, I tried to modify the README.md and it reflects on both places (github and packagist).

How to fix this? The other vendor, I'm dependent on, has a stable release of his package (version 0.0.1), but composer still tries to install "dev-master".

Comment: Can you share link/name of this package?

Comment: This is the github repository of my package: https://github.com/ABPAM/ekatte
This is the Packagist page of it: https://packagist.org/packages/abpam/ekatte

This is the github repository of the dependency pakage: https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader
And this is it's Packagist page: https://packagist.org/packages/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader

Comment: You have explicitly required `dev-master` in tagged version of your package: https://github.com/ABPAM/ekatte/blob/0.0.1/composer.json#L10

Comment: Fixed it, but still when I go `composer require abpam/ekatte` it returns: `abpam/ekatte 0.0.1 requires nuovo/spreadsheet-reader dev-master -> satisfiable by nuovo/spreadsheet-reader[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.`

Comment: Try `composer clearcache` and delete `vendor` and `composer.lock` in your project - it is already fine at packagist, so you probably have cached old data. You shouldn't edit pushed tag BTW - it ma be a source of many problems.

Comment: My God! Worked like a charm! Thank you very much, Rob! Also, I haven't edited the tag, I did something way dumber: deleted it and created it anew :) But the repo is new, almost noone knows about it yet, so it shouldn't be a big deal :) Thank you!